# How to preg_replace html tags?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Please help to make preg_replace regex to change html tags to "BB"

```
<img src="URL" style="max-width: 780px;"/> 
<div id="center">TEXT</div> 
<a href="http://href.li/?URL" target="blank">$1</a> 
<iframe width="780" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/TEXT" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
<strong>TEXT</strong>

[img]$1[/img] 
[center]$1[/center] 
[link]$1[/link] 
[video]$1[/video] 
[strong]$1[/strong]
```

OK. I did it

```
%<img src=\"*(.*?)\".*>%
```

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/156811)

Comment: I get string from mysql like text/plain. 
preg_replace('/<br\\s*?\/??>/i', '\n', $row['description']); 
And it works. Maybe I asked the question wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is not really a pattern for a simple replace (different attributes from different tags are needed in newly named bb-tags), an indivdual regex for each replacement pair could help:

```
$rx_map = array(
'~<strong>(.*?)</strong>~is'                    => '[strong]\1[/strong]',
'~<img\s[^>]*\bsrc="([^"]+)".*?/>~is'           => '[img]\1[/img]',
'~<a\s[^>]*\bhref="([^"]+)".*?</a>~is'          => '[link]\1[/link]',
'~<iframe\s[^>]*\bsrc="([^"]+)".*?</iframe>~is' => '[video]\1[/video]',
'~<div\s+id="center">(.*?)</div>~is'            => '[center]\1[/center]',
);

$str = preg_replace(array_keys($rx_map), array_values($rx_map), $str);
```

Used modifiers `i` for caseless and `s` for making the dot also match newlines. This would replace to:

```
[img]URL[/img] 
[center]TEXT[/center] 
[link]http://href.li/?URL[/link] 
[video]//www.youtube.com/embed/TEXT[/video] 
[strong]TEXT[/strong]
```

[test at eval.in](https://eval.in/186289); As others mentioned already, regex is generally not recommended for parsing html. Depending on your data, it might not be the best option to use regex here and lead to problems.

Comment: @user1791020 See updated answer. The opposite thing is possibly a new question :) But sure you'll work that out!